# QGIS Solweig "rays"

Tags: qgis

I have been trying to calculate the Mean Radiant Temperature via the UMEP Solweig Plugin. However I get these "rays" in my Output. Apparently this has to do something with not having an infinite model domain. However I am not exactly shure what this means or how I can change this. Can someone help with this issue?

Kind regards

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking all my layers and values, I realized that my Digital Canoyp Surface Model was still in milimeter instead of meter, which is why my surfaces were not coherent, and therefore these sun "rays" were visible. So I suggest to always check again the input values when something like this occurs.